# Facebook Data Security Policy

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Recently I've received this email from Facebook about one of my apps after Data Security Checkup:

> In working to create a great Platform experience for everyone, we ask developers to ensure the apps they build comply with our Platform Terms and Developer Policies. Your app APPNAME (AppId: **************) doesn't comply with the following:
>
> Platform Terms 6.a.i.1: You must always have in effect and maintain administrative, physical, and technical safeguards that do the following: Meet or exceed industry standards given the sensitivity of the Platform Data
>
> Please make the requested changes by 2021-11-23 at 12:00 PST.

Platform Terms 6.a.i.1 follows to [Developer Data Security Best Practices](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/datasecurity) Page and looks like industry standard.

My app uses Facebook Login with only read permissions for public data, like Instagram posts and comments. No any publishing or management.

What exactly Facebook expecting from me as single developer to update in my app? I have vps on Digital Ocean with server management via Serverpilot with all latest security updates etc. My host protected with CloudFlare Business Plan. I've provided all this info already but receiving bot/automated messages like this and have no idea what to do next. Please help?!

Comment: To avoid this Data Protection Assessment / Checkups just remove `user_friends` permission from your app permissions list. Confirmed by Facebook Support.

Comment: We have removed user_friends permission, but still we are getting Data Protection Assessment / Checkup. Any suggestion?

Comment: @user18853 I guess you will avoid these checks in future but can't cancel current check. Try to contact Facebook support via email you have for this check and explain situation with user_friends removed.

Comment: @user18853 I'm having trouble passing the test. I'm being asked to provide evidence of a hacking test. How do you test your applications and systems for vulnerabilities and security issues? Do you have any advice? Please  5 days left...

Comment: @user18853 try to test your website with immuniweb